# query for succesive customer orders

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I write a query to display the cust_id and cust_name_last for each customer who had orders in two successive months in the current year. (successive meaning they follow each other 'may, june')

for example: customer 3 has orders in May and June of this year.

```
select cust_id, cust_name_last
from customer
where date_sub (order_date, interval 1 month)
and date_sub (order_date, interval 2 months)
```

Comment: Share the schema and how you join the customer table to the order table.

Comment: I just want to know how to find customers with orders in consecutive months in a year

Answer (score 0):

> *"I just want to know how to find customers with orders in consecutive months in a year"*

Could you try this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT month1.cust_id, month1.cust_name_last
FROM customer month1 INNER JOIN customer  month2
    ON month1.cust_id = month2.cust_id
    AND YEAR(month2.order_date) = YEAR(month1.order_date)
    AND MONTH(month2.order_date) - MONTH(month1.order_date) = 1;
```

If you want to find consecutive orders including another years (e.g 2013-12 => 2014-01), need to check overflows something like as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT month1.cust_id, month1.cust_name_last
FROM customer month1 INNER JOIN customer  month2
    ON month1.cust_id = month2.cust_id
    AND (YEAR(month2.order_date) - YEAR(month1.order_date)) * 12 + (MONTH(month2.order_date) - MONTH(month1.order_date)) = 1;
```

If preceding SQL does not work for you, We are highly appreciated when you post your schema and sample data on sqlFiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/.